# A Fourier Series Solution to a PDE - Finding coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I'm asked to find the solution to the following problem. I was going to use Method of Seperation of Variables -and Fourier series- to deal with it. i.e I thought of assuming this equation is seperable, so $U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$. Then I just calculate $U_{xx} = X''(x)T(t)$ and $U_t = X(x)T'(t)$ and plug these ito the following differential equation. However, I am not sure about the given conditions. It resembles Neumann BC but we don't have $u_x(0,t)$. My question is that is there a problem - instead of 
$u_x(0,t)$, $u(0,t)$ is given-? Or can I solve this?
\begin{array} { c } u _ { t } - u _ { x x } = 0 , \quad 0 < x < 1 , t > 0 \\ u ( x , 0 ) = 1 \\ u ( 0 , t ) = 0 \quad u _ { x } ( 1 , t ) = 0 \quad t \geq 0 \end{array}

EDIT: Using Method of Separation of Variables would work.
Assume $U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$. Then plug this into the original pde, get
$XT'-X''T=0$. Then apply boundary conditions get, $X(0)=X'(1)=0$. The rest will done.
However, I have trouble now when it comes to finding coefficients. I got $U(x,t)=
u ( x , t ) = \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } c _ { n } \cdot \sin \left( \frac { \pi n } { 2 } x \right) \cdot e ^ { - \left( \frac { n \pi } { 2 } \right) ^ { 2 } t }
$.

However, now when I try to find $b _ { n } = \int _ { - 1 } ^ { 1 } f ( x ) \cdot \sin \left( \frac { \pi n } { 2 } x \right) \cdot d x = \int _ { - L } ^ { 1 } \sin \left( \frac { \pi n } { 2 } x \right) \cdot d x = 0$ But, $f(x)=1=u(x,0)$. How am I supposed to  find nonzero $b_n$s?

EDIT2: Read comment section.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the conditions, the problem is solvable as is.

Comment: Thanks, I now edited the post but there is another problem came up.
However, now when I try to find $b _ { n } = \int _ { - 1 } ^ { 1 } f ( x ) \cdot \sin \left( \frac { \pi n } { 2 } x \right) \cdot d x = \int _ { - L } ^ { 1 } \sin \left( \frac { \pi n } { 2 } x \right) \cdot d x = 0$ But, $f(x)=1=u(x,0)$. How am I supposed to  find nonzero $b_n$s?

Comment: You're integrating over $[-1,1]$ when your domain is $[0,1]$. You should derive the conditions yourself. You have $$u(x,0)=1=\sum_{n\ge1}c_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\right)$$ Multiply both sides by $\sin(m\pi x/2)$ and integrate over $x\in[0,1]$ $$\int_{0}^{1} 1\cdot\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{2}\right)\ dx=\sum_{n\ge1}c_{n}\int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{2}\right)\ dx$$ The RHS exists only when $n=m$ and the coefficient of each term is $c_{m}/2$. Hence $$\frac{c_{m}}{2}=\int_{0}^{1} 1 \cdot\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{2}\right)\ dx$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, I got your point. Thanks. I realized what I've done wrong as well. The it should have been $sin(\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{2})$ where $n \in N$ instead of $sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2})$